# How do I remove all variable names and leave values only in my export in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

rid <- (c(1:20,NA))
RISN <- (c(1:20, NA))
Fake <- (c(1:20, NA))

df <- tibble(rid, RISN, Fake)

df <- df %>% filter(!is.na(rid) & !is.na(RISN)) %>% select(RISN,rid)

write.xlsx(df, "~/Downloads/df_test.xlsx", asTable = FALSE)
```

I need my export to appear like this with the "rid" and "RISN" column names removed. I'm not sure if this is possible. Does anyone know a way around this? I suspect I need to convert it from a tibble type to something else, but I've tried matrix and it's not working for me.

[image: The columns should contain no headers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use `colNames = FALSE`. While not mentioned in the docs, under the hood `write.xlsx` calls `buildWorkbook` which calls either `writeDataTable` or `writeData`. Hence, you could use arguments mentioned in `?writeDataTable` as well when using `write.xlsx`. These will be passed to `writeDataTable` via `...`.

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(tidyverse)

rid <- (c(1:20,NA))
RISN <- (c(1:20, NA))
Fake <- (c(1:20, NA))

df <- tibble(rid, RISN, Fake)

df <- df %>% filter(!is.na(rid) & !is.na(RISN)) %>% select(RISN,rid)

write.xlsx(df, "df_test.xlsx", asTable = FALSE, colNames = FALSE)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>